# Follow official steps to Generate Google Map API for new project, fail to load into Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a map into my website marking the location of a place.

So I read that I have to generate API from [Official google map API page](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/).

I created a project, setup billing as required.
Then when loading into the Google Cloud Platform, it always throw me an error saying something went wrong:

[image]

How am I going to fix this?

Comment: You should contact Google support. Here you can get support for programming questions. I suppose there could be many reasons why you get this message.

Comment: You can contact Google Maps support via http://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why this error could have been thrown. Often times further evaluation of the error would be required by reviewing the [Stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) as the rootcause cannot immediately be determined just being viewing the Console error message displayed.

For this type of issues, the recommendation is that you contact the [Google Cloud Platform support team](https://cloud.google.com/support/) or you can create a Public issue on the general [Cloud Platform Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list). There is relatively little that can be done on Stack Overflow to help you debug this.

Comment: Why does even google suggest Stackoverflow for these questions? Saying you don't know doesn't help other people. If you can answer, then answer, otherwise, there's a comment section. Don't demotivate others.